# Distributing points for lottery.py

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to get my bot to  distrubute points from a pot from the lottery game when it ends each time.  So each game starts out at 1 point but everytime someone buys a ticket it goes up by a random amount. At the end of fifteen minutes it's supposed to retrieve the players and the pot and based off of where you're ranked in the list your points are determined. So basically if you're first in the list you win over the pot value. And when the ranking goes down your points that you win go down and if your near or at last place you lose points. The sum of all the points that the players earn does not have to equal 0 after they are distrubuted.

For example: Tim got 1st in the lottery. He should get `5676*1.66`. Also, all the points you receive from the pot should be different based on your rank in the lottery. But if you're at the end of the list in the lottery you should lose points.

This is what I have so far:

```
lotteryStart = time.time()
players = []
pot = 1

def buyLottery(name):
  if name not in players:
  amount = int("30")
  if Point.getCost(name, amount) == True:
    multiplier = random.randint(217, 453)
    pot = int(multiplier+pot)
    different = float(time.time() - lotteryStart)
    years = int(different / Point.YEAR)
    days = int((different % Point.YEAR) / Point.DAY)
    hours = int((different % Point.DAY) / Point.HOUR)
    mins = int((different % Point.HOUR) / Point.MINUTE)
    secs = int(different % Point.MINUTE)
    if secs <= 0:
      if len(players) > 0:
        random.shuffle(players)
        for i in range(1,len(players)): 
           if i == 1:
             pot2 = int(pot*1.66)
           elif i == 2:
             pot2 = int(pot*1.33)
           elif i == 3:
             pot2 = int(pot)
           elif i == 4:
              pot = int(pot/1.66) #And so on but i dont want to keep doing elif
```

Comment: How will the points be determined?

Comment: By the ranking. I'm planning on using player[i]

Comment: Should the sum of all the points be 0?  There are many ways to accomplish what you want, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: I don't want the sum to be 0. I want it to be around the pot value and then lower than the pot value. And then into the negatives.

Comment: Instead of asking "this is my code, how do I fix it?" the better approach would be to extract a general problem from your code, then to make an example that works all by it self so other people can follow your problem, and finally ask a question around that example instead. People usually don't take the time to do this hard work for you.

Comment: I would love to fix it but it's not broken. I just need to know a way on how to get the code to ditrubute the points.

Comment: I guess that means my queston will not be answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *do not* understand your lottery; I can't imagine a lottery where you buy a ticket for a random amount and could lose money on top of the ticket price being very popular in real life!

That being said, I think you want to do something like this:

```
ratios = []
for i in range(-2, len(players) - 2):
    if i < 0:
       ratios.append(1 - (i * 0.33)) # ratio > 1
    else:
        ratios.append(1 / (1 + (i * 0.33))) # ratio <= 1
winnings = [pot * r for r in ratios]
```

You can then easily match `players[i]` with their `winnings[i]`. Note that I have assumed that you missed out `pot / 1.33` accidentally; otherwise, you will have to adjust this slightly.

For 10 players, I get:

```
ratios == [1.6600000000000001, 1.33, 1.0, 0.7518796992481203, 
           0.6024096385542168, 0.5025125628140703, 0.43103448275862066, 
           0.3773584905660377, 0.33557046979865773, 0.3021148036253776]
```

Comment: Uh question though. How would I tell what place their in by using a loop?

Comment: What place who is in? Your shuffled list of `players` has the same length as `winnings`, so you can use `for i in range(len(players)):` to get indices for both.

Comment: No problem. It's worth noting, though, that despite what you say in your question, with this formula nobody ever has negative winnings.

Comment: Well that's okay. xD i still like your idea a lot better than mine.